# listview scrolling with images

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app,i have a listview with image and text.when the user clicks in the listview,the image in that row will change.the problem is when user scrolls the listview.the changed image is not showing.but later it is appearing...please provide me a solution or code to avoid this.

thanks in advance..

Comment: are you updating data source for adapter, means image source changed there also.

Comment: changed image in getview() method.

Comment: can you post your getView code here, so one can help you.

Comment: did you get it working? your comment in not clear.

Comment: 'public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            imageView.setImageResource(itemToggled[position] ? R.drawable.ic_launcher : R.drawable.tick);
            return itemView;
        }'

Comment: why don't you have both these drawables in onCreate() method. Drawable normal=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);

Answer (score 2):

What's the size of the images that are used for each item in the listview.

When scrolling the image needs to be redrawn and if the images are of a larger size it can take time to redraw.

Make sure the images are only as big as they need to be for the item

Comment: Whats the dimensions of the image. I believe android decompresses the image when it is opened (jpg/png etc are compressed data before they are opened). so even though the initial file size is 4kb it may not be when it is opened.

Comment: I don't think the image size is a problem

Comment: I don't think so either. Those dimensions are fine. It might just be the device your running on.

Comment: now it is working..problem was with the getview().so many condition statements in getview() caused the problem.